# Would this distribtuion be considered half-normal?

Tags: distributions, skewness

I'm a bit confused because of the high skewness value.:

[image]

[image]

Edit: By half-normal, I was going by this Wikipedia page:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution
Maybe I'm mistaken?

Comment: You’re asking why this is not half-normal, but the question remains why would you think of this distribution as if half-normal? You could use many different distributions for this data, so why half-normal?

Comment: The right tail looks too long/heavy for a half-normal (also shown with high skewness, kurtosis and sd/mean)

Comment: If the minimum is positive, I would try looking at logarithms.  But the graph doesn't rule that you may have a mixture of zeros and positive values. `PromSpend` suggests prom expenditure and perhaps some students didn't go. You tell us.

Answer (score 1):

There are many distributions of shape similar to the empirical distribution shown. You can create “half” distributions from any symmetric distribution centered at zero by taking absolute value of the random variable, e.g. half-normal, half-$t$, half-Laplace, etc. There are also other distributions like exponential or power distribution that have similar shape. Without additional details it’s hard to impossible to judge which one would fit the problem best. What can be said is that your data has long tails, what makes half-normal rather poor candidate.